# I have this stored procedure, and I want to show the return value of stored procedure on a label of my form

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this stored procedure, and I want to show the return value of stored procedure on a label of my form:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Get_LastProfId
AS
    SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('EDU_Professor') AS Current_Identity; 
GO
```

Now how can I get the return value of this procedure in ASP.NET? My procedure just returns the last identity id value of my table.

Comment: Hey dorsa, you need to be more specific. Are you using ASP.NET MVC? What is your data access stack? (ADO.NET, Entity Framework, Dapper).

Comment: May be you could use output variable in stored procedure and return that. It is very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ADO.NET`, you can use `ExecuteScalar()` method to get the value. Follow the following example.

```
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Get_LastProfId", conn))
   {
     command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                       
     int returnIdentity = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
   }
```